# How do I include my css file, while using Java and Spring with thymeleaf?

Tags: java, css, spring, thymeleaf

I have tried different apporaches. For me, most logical would be the standard way, as I have it now in my "Item.html":

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${item.name}"></title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

This is the form what "drag and drop" in netbeans gives me as a path.

My file structure is shown here:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a directory `static` in your `src/main/resources/` folder.
2. Create a directory `css` in created `static` folder to store css files.
3. Put the `css` files to the `css` folder.
4. In html you can include `css` like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>`

**Here the `static` folder to serve static contents like `css`, `js` files.**